# How to change Target URL

Tags: java

I have developed an application which contacts a Sun One web server. The Web Server has Lotus domino and SiteMinder Plugin.

Below is the URL for the application

```
http://HostName.example.com
```

After hitting the URL in the browser, the URL is redirect to webserver and a login page appears with below URL.

```
http://HostName.example.com:9898/SiteMinderagent/forms/login.fcc?TYPE=
33554433&REALMOID=06-1716e557-15f3-100f-b9a4-835cc8200cb3&GUID=&SMAUTHREASON=
0&METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=$SM$sHjbzl4f9R%2bcSa0%2fEgnu6oUQQPMQnUgkU6Zvx5zWZpQ%
3d&TARGET=$SM$http%3a%2f%2fshivalik%2ered%2eiplanet%2ecom%3a9898%2fvalidation%
2findex%2ehtml
```

After logging into the application, the request is redirect using the TARGET parameter( URL is decoded in the application) from the URL  Now the login doesnot work if i block the HTTP requests. As the **TARGET** parameter is a HTTP request, I am unable to login into the application.

Is there any way I can change the TARGET parameter to HTTPS. Can i know in which file I can change it in the WebServer. The Sun One Web Server runs Solaris OS. I have tried hard finding the solution as I think the URL is appended with Query strings like **SMAGENTNAME**, **SMAUTHREASON**, **TARGET** in the Servlet of the Domino.

Answer (score 1):

The TARGET parameter is populated with the URL originally presented by the user - i.e. in your example http://HostName.example.com will result in the TARGET query string parameter containing the same URL plus the other parameters generated by the SiteMinder agent.

Possible solutions in your case could be to hardcode the TARGET by putting something like the following on the top of login.fcc:

```
@TARGET=https://hostname.example.com/
```

That would cause the FCC to ignore the query string parameter that is POSTed and instead will hardcode it.

Alternatively if you need to preserve the path component of the URL (e.g. http://hostname.example.com/path/to/file.html) you could add some javascript to the FCC page. The standard implementation populates TARGET into an  element so you could use JavaScript to parse the value and replace http:// with https:// if required. Make sure that your Agent Configuration has single and double quotes in BadFormChars (`BadFormChars=%22,%27`) to prevent XSS attacks.

There is also an Agent Config parameter `HttpsPort` that you can use to "trick" SiteMinder into thinking you're serving HTTPS traffic out of port 80 but you will have to test for any unintended side effects.

Comment: Where can be the value @TARGET can be changed? Is it at the SiteMinder. In which it should be changed